# How can i write a rule for uptime monitoring (urls) in elastalert2?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert2

How can i write a rule for uptime monitoring (urls) in elastalert2? Can you share any example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to monitor urls. if they are down, it should alert @AnkurLahiry